# problem with dynamicallly adding values to dropdown box

Tags: javascript, html

i want to dynamically add options to drop down boxes

```
  var x =document.getElementById("c");
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text="hhh"
    optn.value="val"
    x.options.add(optn);
```

I am doing it inside  a loop,with diff values of for val and hhh.Bur sometime i dont see any any values in drop down box , what may be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one:**

```
var objSelect = document.getElementById("subComponentOSID");
objSelect.options[objSelect.options.length] = new Option('1','1');
objSelect.options[objSelect.options.length] = new Option('2','2');
```

Answer (score 0):

`add` is a method of HTMLSelectElement objects, not of HTMLCollection objects.

```
x.add(optn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the element with the id "subComponentOSID", the only apparent issues in your javascript are missing semicolons on the lines where you assign values to `optn.text` and `optn.value`.  Also, while most browsers will resolve what you mean when calling the `add` function on an options collection for a select element, you should move your add to the select itself.  See the [Mozilla reference for HTMLSelectElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement), which provides an example.

In the meantime, try replacing the code snippet you provided with this:

```
var x =document.getElementById("subComponentOSID");
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text="hhh";  //Added semi-colon
optn.value="val";  //Added semi-colon
x.add(optn);  // Moved add to HTMLSelectElement
```